# Euler-style integral equations

Tags: special-functions

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m \le n$.
The integral 
$$\int_0^1 p^m (1-p)^{n-m} dp$$
is well studied and can be written in the form $D_n W_m U_{n-m}$.
My question concerns identifying the class of all measurable functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, up to null sets, such that
$$\int_0^1 p^m (1-p)^{n-m} f(p) dp = D_n W_m U_{n-m} $$
holds for all $n$ and $m \le n$.
Clearly $f(p) = p^a (1-p)^b$ a.e. continues to have this form. Can anyone see an argument for why these might be the only functions with this property?